# PHP imap_createmailbox issue

Tags: php, imap

I am using **imap_createmailbox** to create a custom folder as a subfolder of INBOX in a dovecot mailbox.The folder is getting created but the problem is it does not show up under the list of folders unless I "subscribe" to it from my squirrel mail. Is there anyway to this from PHP?

I am using this

```
  function imap_create_folder($folder_name)
        {
            return imap_createmailbox($this->conn, $folder_name);
        }
```

Comment: php.net/manual/en/function.imap-subscribe.php ?

Answer (score 1):

extract from my own project:

```
$currentlySubscribed = array_map(function($e){
    return $e->name;
}, imap_getsubscribed($conn, $mailbox, '*');

$toSubscribe = array_diff($expected, $currentlySubscribed);

foreach($toSubscribe as $subscribeMe){
    if(!imap_subscribe($conn, $subscribeMe)){
        throw new RuntimeException('Failed to subscribe');
    }
}
```